# Facebook like mod_rewrite with ajax page loading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook, url-rewriting

This is kind of just a general information question so that I can implement it in a site later, but I was wondering how facebook does their mod_rewrite.

To be more explanatory, usually when a site has any kind of ajax page load you see a #/page-name in the address bar. On facebook the url appears just like a normal friendly url. How would you use mod_rewrite to rewrite something like that? or is it something else?

Comment: the question is not clear. explain which exact behaviour looks so exotic for you (but most likely it is not mod_rewrite work) ps: I bet for `history rewriting` but let's wait for your further explanations

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook and Ajax](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5792859/facebook-and-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, too, thought it was `mod_rewrite`. However, because the pages are loaded asynchronously, there is no invocation of `mod_rewrite`. I googled, it, came back to SO, and was linked to this, which details the `pushState()` method, it may help.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

It may not degrade gracefully into browsers not using HTML5, but then again, it might. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Most sites I've seen using `pushState` degrade gracefully to the hash technique.

Answer (score 0):

The hash part of a url never reaches your server (I don't think). You catch it with javascript and load the page with ajax.
See http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html for something similar.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/ is a simple way to handle it.

Comment: He did not ask about hash-bang. He asked about similar behaviour but **without** anchors

Answer (score 0):

`PushState` alone isn't all that friendly across browsers and versions, so if you want it to degrade nicely you need to do a lot of checking for HTML5 feature support and whatnot. Fortunately, there is a nice package called **History JS** that handles this very well. Though it provides a plethora of options for tailoring to your needs, you can basically just plug it in and go without worrying too much about compatibility/degrading on various browsers.

https://github.com/browserstate/History.js